# Deprecation of combine_options in Active Storage's ImageProcessing transformer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

While developing a new Rails Application, I noticed the following deprecation warning in the console:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Active Storage's ImageProcessing transformer doesn't support :combine_options, as it always generates a single ImageMagick command. Passing :combine_options will not be supported in Rails 6.1.

This is also mentioned in the [Rails 6 release notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_0_release_notes.html):

> Deprecate :combine_options in Active Storage's ImageProcessing transformer without replacement.

Now I'm wondering:

- What we are supposed to use in the future to be able to things such
  as: `<%= image_tag @category.image.variant(combine_options: {
  resize_to_fill: [800,50] }, gaussian_blur: ['0x1.5']), class:
  "card-img-top" if @category.image.attached? %>`
- What would be the reason for deprecating this functionality?

Comment: You're far more likely to get an answer and people are far more likely to discover this post when you spell "deprecation" correctly.

Answer (score 10):

I should have looked better in the [API Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html).

`ActiveStore.Variant` takes multiple arguments directly. Taking my example above, the following works and will continue to work:

```
<%= image_tag @category.image.variant(resize_to_fill: [800,50], gaussian_blur: ['0x1.5']), class: "card-img-top" if @category.image.attached? %>
```

As a result there's no need to use `combine_options`.

Comment: This generates a new variant hash key right? So any previous image upgraded to this syntax will generate a new image?